# Acessing element of an array which is a element in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, element, using

Currently I am working on a project where I have to transform a Matlab code into a Python code.
Now I am stuck on small problem which might be a big problem.

For example  I have a Matrix and I want to give the positions [0][i] the value lets say 1 and i is 0 to 5.
The Matrix is 4x4 (to small for [0][5]) but on position [0][0] is an array with 3 elements.

So it would look like `code`M = [[array, 1 , 2, 3],
[array, 1 , 2, 3],
[array, 1 , 2, 3]]`code`   and array would just be`code` array =[1,2,3]. `code`

> > > I hope I descripted it clear. Feel free to ask more :D

Now the problem which I have is that I want the first element of the array is [0][0] so that the number 3 in the first row ist [0][5]. Is it possible to declare the first element of an array to the matrix position [0][0]?
I am grateful for every solutions or ideas. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is better solution to use iterable **unpacking operator(*)** to unpack your iterables

Unpacking in Python refers to an operation that consists of assigning an iterable of values to a tuple (or list ) of variables in a single assignment statement.

Example:

```
array =[1,2,3]
M = [[*array, 1 , 2, 3], [*array, 1 , 2, 3], [*array, 1 , 2, 3]]
print (M) # [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]]
print (M[0][5]) # 3
```

Or **add value at beginning of list**, there are several solutions, here is one of the examples:

```
array =[1,2,3]
M = [[array, 1 , 2, 3], [array, 1 , 2, 3], [array, 1 , 2, 3]]
M = [[0,0]+l for l in M]
print (M) # [[0, 0, [1, 2, 3], 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, [1, 2, 3], 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, [1, 2, 3], 1, 2, 3]]
print (M[0][5]) # 3
```

Also you can use Python **insert() function**:

The insert() method inserts an element to the list at the specified index.

> **Syntax**: list.insert(idx, elem)

```
for l in M:
    l.insert(0,0)
    l.insert(1,0)
print (M) # [[0, 0, [1, 2, 3], 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, [1, 2, 3], 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, [1, 2, 3], 1, 2, 3]]
print (M[0][5]) # 3
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your solution! It helped a lot! But does it also work with 2dimensional matrix ?

Comment: @pypy youre welcome, I’m glad it helped. for new questions its better to write new post